# export plotly as self-contained html in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, r, plotly

In JavaScript, how to export plotly plot as a self-contained html file? Just like in R, we can use `saveWidget` function. How to do it with JavaScript?

**Edit**

I tried to use

```
var a = document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("a")
    );
    a.download = "export.html";
    a.href = "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
    a.click();
```

But it does work well because it loses all the event, etc.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqZqWX

Comment: Not sure, but maybe [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, thanks. it seems that phantomjs can only capture screenshot, and save as PNG format, JPEG, GIF, and PDF. What I really want is to save as .html file..

Answer (score 1):

You can download `plotly.js` and then call [Plotly.newPlot](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlynewplot) method.

Here are step details.

### Get plotly script text

```
async function getPlotlyScript() {
  // fetch
  const plotlyRes = await fetch('https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.js')
  // get response as text
  return await plotlyRes.text() 
}
```

### Get plotly chart data

We need to pass the current chart state in `Plot.newPlot` method. If the chart data and layout are not controlled by your code, don't worry. The DOM element where plotly builds the chart contains `data` and `layout`.

```js
function getChartState () {
  const el = document.getElementById('your plotly container id')
  return {
    data: el.data, // current data
    layout: el.layout // current layout
  }
}
```

### Compose HTML

Now we have everything to compose our HTML. Don't forget to:

- add `charset="utf-8"` because plotly script has special characters.
- escape closing script tag to make browser consider it as a string, not as a tag

```js
async function getHtml() {
  const plotlyModuleText = await getPlotlyScript()
  const state = getChartState()

  return `
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
      </head>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        ${plotlyModuleText}
      <\/script>
    
      <div id="plotly-output"></div>
      
      <script type="text/javascript">
        Plotly.newPlot(
          'plotly-output', 
          ${JSON.stringify(state.data)},
          ${JSON.stringify(state.layout)}
        )
    <\/script>
  `
}
```

#### Download HTML document

```js
async function exportToHtml () {
  // Create URL
  const blob = new Blob([await getHtml()], { type: 'text/html' })
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

  // Create downloader
  const downloader = document.createElement('a')
  downloader.href = url
  downloader.download = 'export.html'

  // Trigger click
  downloader.click()

  // Clean up
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
}

exportToHtml()
```